# Error for Null value when opening a registry key in C#

Tags: c#

I'm having an issue for C# (I'm new to it), when trying to fix a Null value.
   Therefore I have a variable "verif" (String verif = String.Empty;), which I used it to read some key from Windows Registry. My code works if the key exists, but when it doesn't I got the error"NullReferanceException was unhandled". 
   I tried several ways, to catch the exception, to put an "If" statement but I failed miserable.
   My code is something like this:

```
RegistryKey key_user;
RegistryKey key_pwd;
String code = String.Empty;
String tara = String.Empty;
String tot = String.Empty;
String pwd_mdw = String.Empty;
String user_mdw = String.Empty;
String user_uca = String.Empty;
String pwd_uca = String.Empty;
String verif = String.Empty;     
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{tot = listBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
//MessageBox.Show(tot);
tara = tot.Substring(tot.Length - 2, 2);
//MessageBox.Show(tara);
code = listBox1.SelectedValue.ToString().Substring(0, 2);
user_mdw = textBox1.Text;
//MessageBox.Show(user_mdw);
pwd_mdw = textBox2.Text;
//MessageBox.Show(pwd_mdw);        
if (code == "CC")
{
verif = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\TDCredentials").GetValue("user_mdw_" + tara + "_CC").ToString();
MessageBox.Show("Verif",verif);
MessageBox.Show(user_mdw, "user_mdw");
if (verif==null)
{
key_user = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\\TDCredentials");
key_user.SetValue("user_mdw_" + tara + "_CC", user_mdw);
key_user.Close();
key_pwd = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\\TDCredentials");
key_pwd.SetValue("pass_mdw_" + tara + "_CC", pwd_mdw);
key_pwd.Close();
MessageBox.Show("User and Password inserted successfully!");
textBox1.Clear();
textBox2.Clear();
}
else
{...
```

Any hints?
Many thanks in advance, Bogdan.

Comment: If you run this in debug mode in Visual Studio, which line does it indicate as the one throwing the unhandled exception?  Also, you might get some value out of Microsoft's C# Programmer's Guide's article on [Exceptions and Exception Handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173160.aspx)

Comment: The error is for "verif" variable, at line "verif = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\TDCredentials").GetValue("user_mdw_" + tara + "_CC").ToString();" and only when there is no registry key which will meet the demand. For example, there is the registry key "JOHN" with the value "100" and my variable, "verif" searches for it. If "JOHN" exists, as a registry key value, then the code has no error. If not C# raises me the error mentioned in the thread, null value unhandled.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at what you're trying to do, this line is most likely (one of) your problems;

```
verif = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\TDCredentials")
            .GetValue("user_mdw_" + tara + "_CC").ToString();
```

If the key does not exist, `OpenSubKey` will return null, and you call `GetValue()` on it without checking.

You can change the line to add a check, something like;

```
var key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\TDCredentials");
var value = key != null ? key.GetValue("user_mdw_" + tara + "_CC") : null;
verif = value != null ? value.ToString() : null;

if(verif == null) { 
...
```

Comment: Hello Joachim, I have used your idea but same error for: verif = key != null ? key.GetValue("user_mdw_" + tara + "_CC").ToString() : null;

Comment: @BogdanM Sorry, updated the answer, the `ToString()` had the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you need to check

```
Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\TDCredentials")
```

that this is not null. Then call the `getvalue` method. Beause if the above key is null then the following getvalue will throw exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following check to test if `Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\TDCredentials")` is not `null` else it will bomb:

```
 if (code == "CC")
        {
            if (Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\TDCredentials") != null)
            {
                verif =
                    Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\TDCredentials").GetValue("user_mdw_" + "Test" + "_CC").
                        ToString();

            }
```

Comment: it's no use to check the hole registry key..."Software\TDCredentials" because it may be already used by other keys. I have to check for one specific key value...so it does not help

Answer (score 0):

Try checking for NULL on OpenSubKey() & GetValue() methods prior to using  ToString() method.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to do too much in one line, without checking the results as you go.

First of all, as others have already said, you need to check that `OpenSubKey` doesn't return null. You also need to make sure that the key is closed when you're finished, with a `using` statement:

```
using (var key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\TDCredentials"))
{
    if (key == null)
    {
        // Couldn't open the key, now what?
        // You need to make a decision here.
        // If you read the documentation for CreateSubKey,
        // you'll see that it can *also* return null, so don't rely on it.
    }
    else
    {
        // OK, opened the key, and the using statement will close it.
        // Now we can try reading values. See the next part of the answer.
    }
}
```

If you successfully open the key, you can try to read the value. Even if you successfully open the key, the value might not exist, or it might not be a string (it could be a DWORD, for instance, or a binary value).

- If the value doesn't exist, `GetValue` returns null, so calling `ToString` without checking will throw `NullReferenceException`.
- Even if the value exists, calling `ToString` on it is the **wrong** thing to do, because it might not be a string value in the registry. If it's a binary value, for example, calling `ToString` on it will give you the string `System.Byte[]`. You need to check that it is actually a string.

```
else
{
    // OK, opened the key, and the using statement will close it.
    // Now we can try reading values.
    string verif = key.GetValue("user_mdw_" + tara + "_CC") as string;
    if (verif == null)
    {
        // The value does not exist, or is not the type you expected it to be (string).
        // Now what? You need to make a decision here.
    }
    else
    {
        // OK, do something with verif.
    }
}
```

Make sure to read the documentation for these methods, and handle the special cases they mention, especially the circumstances under which they return null:

- [CreateSubKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ad51f2dx.aspx)
- [OpenSubKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9f66s0a.aspx)
- [GetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fdf576x1.aspx)